# Nested loop for reading two files with bash

Tags: bash

I'm currently trying to use the following code to merge two input files:

```
for i in `cat $file1`; do
    for j in `cat $file2`; do
        printf "%s %s\n" "$i" "$j"
    done
done
```

Given files created as follows:

```
printf '%s\n' A B C >file1
printf '%s\n' 1 2 3 >file2
```

...my expected/desired output is:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

But instead, the output I'm getting is:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
C 2
C 3
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Sorry for that. I just editted my question.

Comment: And btw: grab good reads: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 2):

Possible by using the pr command from coreutils, also possible with other commands/tools like paste and also by Shell and AWK scripts.
Least effort by using the commands from coreutils as only a few parameters are required on the commandline, like in this example:

```
pr -TmJS" " file1 file2
```

where:

- `-T` turns off pagination
- `-mJ` merge files, Joining full lines
- `-S" "` separate the columns with a blank

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "have been asked and answered many times before".

Answer (score 1):

The following command will work:

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2
```

The [paste](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) coreutils utility merges files line by line. The `-d` options is used to specify the delimeter, ie. space here.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! It works . Do you know if there is any alternative way to get the same result with a loop ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...consider the usual chiding about answering an obvious duplicate to have taken place.

Comment: @elias, follow the "already has an answer here" links at the top of the question; you'll see many of the existing instances of this question have something like `while IFS= read -r line1 <&3 && IFS= read -r line2 <&4; do echo "Read $line1 from file-1 and $line2 from file-2"; done 3<file1 4<file2` suggested as an answer.